# Servidor ionic não inicia

Tags: ionic

Estou iniciando um projeto em ionic (versão 1), porém meu servidor não inicia mais.

Eu digito `ionic serve --lab`, aparece a seguinte mensagem:

```
Starting server (address: 0.0.0.0, port: 8100, dev server port: 53703, livereload port: 35729) - Ctrl+C to cancel
[OK] Development server running!
     Local: http://localhost:8100
     External: http://192.168.1.5:8100
     DevApp: AluraCar@8100 on DESKTOP-PQPJV63
```

Mas quando coloco `localhost:8100` no navegador ele diz que não está iniciado.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Experimenta digitar apenas **ionic serve** para iniciar o servidor

Answer (score 0):

É possível que o seu código esteja com erros, verifique o código na hora de atribuir os valores, que esteja assim:

```
private foo: number;
private foo = 100;
```

e não assim:

```
private foo = number;
private foo: 100;
```

Comment: Mas onde ficam esses valores?